# LINQ to Entities does not support extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two extension methods like this

```
  public static IQueryable<T> CurrentVersion(this IQueryable<T> queryable, DateTime date)
  {
        return queryable.Where(p => p.CreationDate>date);
  }

  public static IEnumerable<T> CurrentVersion(this IEnumerable<T> queryable, DateTime date)
  {
        return queryable.Where(p => p.CreationDate>date);
  }
```

My model is

```
public class Group {
    ..
    ICollection<GroupMembers> GroupMembers { get; set; }
}
```

When I use from extension method in this query everything is ok

```
 var q =  Db.Groups.CurrentVersion();
 var result = q.ToList();
```

But when I use it in flowing query I get an error

```
 var q = Db.Groups.SelectMany(p => p.GroupMembers.AsQueryable().CurrentVersion(date));

OR

 var q = Db.Groups.SelectMany(p => p.GroupMembers.AsEnumerable().CurrentVersion(date));

 var result = q.ToList();    // Here I get error
```

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[..](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[..., System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Now I have two questions:

1. I googled this error and found many problems same as my question in stackoverflow. All answers were "Linq to Entities can't convert this extension method to a SQL query". Now I would be grateful if somebody help me to know, why does my first query not raise any errors?
2. How can I change my extension method which can be recognized by Linq-to-Entities?

Answer (score 8):

Linq query needs to be translated to sql. When you have your CurrentVersion extension called inline like this:

```
Db.Groups.CurrentVersion();
```

then EF just invokes CurrentVersion method, gets resulting IQueryable object and transforms in to query. On the other hand in case of that query:

```
var q = Db.Groups.SelectMany(p => p.GroupMembers.AsQueryable().CurrentVersion(date));
```

The inner expression in SelectMany may not be ever invoked in code! It is meant to be translated to sql. So it is treated as Expression object and it is then parsed, but in your case it contains Invoke Expression as you are invoking method but this cannot be translated to sql from obvious reason. So from within SelectMany lambda parameer you cannot invoke any method, you have to provide there proper Expression. The most valuable thing provided by CurrentVersion method is filtering expression. Change your method like this:

```
public static Expression<T, bool> CurrentVersion( DateTime date)
{
    return p => p.CreationDate > date;
}
```

An use it like this:

```
var q =  Db.Groups.Where(ExpressionsHelper.CurrentVersion(date));
...
Expression<T, bool> filterExpression = ExpressionsHelper.CurrentVersion(date);
Db.Groups.SelectMany(p => p.GroupMembers.AsQueryable().Where(filterExpression));
```

If you whish you may stil have your extension method sharing filtering logic with the new method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> CurrentVersion(this IQueryable<T> queryable, DateTime date)
{
    return queryable.Where(ExpressionsHelper.CurrentVersion(date));
}
```

Comment: I think your extension no different with my extension method because   queryable.Where(ExpressionsHelper.CurrentVersion(date)) is equale with    queryable.Where(p => p.CreationDate>date);

Comment: Indeed queryable.Where(ExpressionsHelper.CurrentVersion(date))  should work as queryable.Where(p => p.CreationDate>date); but this was the goal, right? I changed your method so that your filtering logic may be reused, as you whished. So the difference should be that method proposed by me is working and EF can parse it to query.

Comment: But my version of CurrentVersion extension method cannot be applied to your nested query! You may use it only with simple queries like Db.Groups.CurrentVersion(); For complex ones you need to use Db.Groups.SelectMany(p => p.GroupMembers.AsQueryable().Where(ExpressionsHelper.CurrentVersion(date))); The extension method is presented only as sample - if you whish to have it, you can have it without code duplication.

Comment: So how can I implement a method that can use it in nested query?

Comment: Please look carefully at my answer once more :) First write method public static Expression<T, bool> CurrentVersion( DateTime date)
{
    return p => p.CreationDate > date;
} (not extension method!). Then use it Db.Groups.SelectMany(p => p.GroupMembers.AsQueryable().Where(ExpressionsHelper.CurrentVersion(date)));

Comment: Just forget about Extension method. It is confusing you. In my opinion you cannot use it at all in nested queries. They are helpful for simpler cases.

Comment: You mean there isn't any way that create an extension method to support this issue?

Comment: I see no reasonable way to achieve what you want with extension method, but there is a way to share part of the logic from your method with static method (for example) so that we may achieve something similar to what you originally wanted.